# Create child processes from array not working

Tags: arrays, c, process, multiprocessing, fork

I don't understand which logic to use to open the problem. I don't have a hierarchy I need to have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
//prototype(s)
void createChild(int numberOfChild);
//array with size
int main() {
    int arr[] = {2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0}; // arr of integer number
    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(int); // number of element
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        createChild(arr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
 }

void createChild(int numberOfChild){
    pid_t pid;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < numberOfChild; i++) {
        pid = fork();
        if (pid < 0) { printf("error. can't create process\n"); }
        else if (pid == 0) { //child process
            printf("[son] pid %d from [parent] pid %d\n", getpid(), getppid()); 
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfChild; ++i) {
        wait(NULL);
    }
}
```

Given an array of integers, I need to write a program for each father to create a number of sons corresponding to the array in the array.
For example, if the array is `{2,3,1,0,0,0,0}`. Father number 0 has 2 sons, father number 1 has 3 sons, father number 3 has 1 son and so on. For each process, print pid number and pid number of his father. The count of the fathers is in the form level order.

[image]

I don't want to use shared memory with pipe or something else.

Comment: What does this print? And what do you want to print instead? Fix a code block with actual output and then a codeblock with correct output.

Comment: You cannot create the expected process structure by using a loop in `main` calling a function that calls `fork`. Every child process needs to know its number and has to `fork` again if necessary. It is difficult to decide which numbers to assign to the children because other processes create children as well.

Comment: ... Process 1 needs to know that 0 will also create number 2, so 3 will be the next free number for the children of 1; 2 needs to know that numbers 3, 4, 5 will be created by 1 and 6 will be the next free number. The array does not contain enough information to describe the process tree. If you don't want to use IPC to assign the number/index to the processes, process 0 could use an algorithm to pre-calculate an the index of the first child for every parent, maybe store it in an additional array like `{1, 3, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0}` in addition to `arr`. Is this some kind of homework?

Comment: @Bodo how can i precalculate like you recommand ? how can i find the index of the fitrst child and storage inside variable ?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a homework question.

The task seems to assume that the child processes are created after each other in the order of the process number/index. *This is not true for a real system*. If process 0 creates process 1 first then process 2, it is likely - but not guaranteed - that process 1 starts creating children before process 2. It is not defined when the children of processes 1 and 2 get created. The order might be 3, 4, 5, 6 or 3, 4, 6, 5 or 3, 6, 4, 5 or 6, 3, 4, 5. This means, every process needs to know in advance which process numbers its children are supposed to get.

**Idea for an algorithm**

As spedified in the question, the array `int arr[] = {2, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0};` defines the number of children. The index of the main process is `i = 0`, the first child will get index 1.

- Create an array for every process' children start index `startIndex` with the same size as `arr`.
- Set `start = 1`
- Loop over the arrays using index `i`

  - <strike>If the expected number of children `arr[i]` is not 0</strike> <sup>(*)</sup>

    - The start index for process `i`'s children (if any) will be `start`. Save it in `startIndex[i] = start;`
    - As the process is supposed to create `arr[i]` children, increment `start` by `arr[i]`.
  - <strike>else</strike>

    - <strike>set `startIndex[i] = 0;`</strike>
  - increment `i` and repeat according to the number of elements in `arr`.

<sup>(*)</sup> My first idea was to store start index 0 if no children are to be created, but the distinction is not necessary as `arr[i] = 0` is sufficient to indicate "no children", and `startIndex[i]` can be ignored in this case.

After the loop,  `startIndex[i]` should contain the index of the first child to be created by process `i` and `arr[i]` the number of children.

Then every process has to look up the number and start index of the children by its own index and fork the children in a loop, setting the process index for every child process as required.

Every child will do the same if its expected number of children is not 0. This can be implemented by a recursive function call.

Comment: i tried solution based on your help but i'm stuck. my processes creating also processing for element with 0.

Comment: @rudyhaddad I suggest to write a new question showing your code and the actual and expected output with a reference to this answer. You can get a link by clicking on the gray word `Share` below a question or an answer. Then add a comment here with a link to the new question.